# How to Upload an entire Folder to Box using Python

Tags: python, api, directory, sdk, boxsdk

I'm have an entire folder structure that I would like to upload into BOX. The folder structure looks like this:

```
documents
└── A
    ├── A1
    │   ├── A1A.jpg
    │   └── A1B.jpg
    └── A2
        ├── A2A.png
        ├── A2B.png
        ├── A2C.jpg
        ├── A2D.jpg
        └── A2E.png
```

I would like to use Python to upload the entire folder structure to a Box folder and maintain the same tree structure. I haven't found any functions in the Python SDK to upload entire folders so I'm wondering if anyone has had a similar use-case and found a Box function to do folder uploads.

I'd ideally like to find a nice one liner before I go down the path of writing a recursive function to do all work.

Cheers!